# siunitx not aligning ranges in table perfectly

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, alignment, threeparttable

I have the problem, that the `S` type column ist not aligning at the interval sign perfectly. See this MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[final, 12pt, USenglish, a4paper]{scrbook}

% UNITS
\usepackage{siunitx}    %for properly using SI units
\sisetup{range-phrase={\hspace{0.08em}--\hspace{0.08em}}, range-units=single}

% TABLES
\usepackage{booktabs}   % formatting table lines: \toprule, \midrule, \bottomrule
%\usepackage{multirow}  % span table cells across multiple cells
\usepackage{caption}    % formatting captions
\captionsetup[table]{singlelinecheck=false, justification=justified}    % aligning table captions on the left
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}  % aligning tablecaptions and notes. wrap tabulars with it: \begin or \end{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \caption{Some MWE:}
        \label{tab:mwe}
        \begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{l|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}S}
            \toprule
            One column              & {Strength\tnote{1} / \si{\kilo\joule\per\mole}}       \\ \midrule
            aaa                     & \numrange{40}{360}                                    \\
            bbb                     & \numrange{40}{200}                                    \\
            ccc                     & \numrange{4}{50}                                      \\
            ddd                     & \numrange{40}{120}                                    \\
            eee                     & \numrange{4}{80}                                      \\
            fff                     & \numrange{0}{50}                                      \\
            ggg                     & \numrange{0}{20}                                      \\ 
            xxx                     & \numrange{4}{40}                                      \\ \midrule 
            iii                     & \numrange{160}{480}                                   \\
            jjj                     & \numrange{80}{320}                                    \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular*}
        \begin{tablenotes}
            \footnotesize
            \item[1] Bla
        \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The `–` sign is aligned perfectly everywhere BUT row iii, where the interval suddenly apparently aligns the `160` centrally above the `80`. Does anybody know how to fix this? I don't really know where to start.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74721/134144 is a related question.

Comment: I am sorry, am I overlooking something? The answer in that linked thread seems to be "dont make a table that long and show the values in seperate columns". That is not an option in my case. I ONLY have ranges and need them beneath each other.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392854/134144 shows how to imitate the look of aligned ranges using 3 different columns. Probably you can make use of that?

Comment: Inspired by [Joseph Wright's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5530/align-number-ranges-in-table#comment8585_5542), you could also use `\begin{tabular*}{0.8\textwidth}{l|@{\extracolsep{\fill}}S[parse-numbers = false,input-decimal-markers={-},output-decimal-marker = \text{\hspace{0.08em}--\hspace{0.08em}}]}` in combination with `40-360`, `40-200`,... in the table.

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked that comment. That is a well-functioning workaround. I just wonder why it doesn't work automatically, what the problem is with that specific row. But thanks nonetheless, do you want to copy your comment into an answer to this topic?